# If and ElseIf statement not working in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I have written the following PowerShell script below:

```
if ($Animal -eq "Chicken") {
    if ($Food -eq "Egg") {
        Write-Host "This chicken eats egg"
    } ElseIf ($Food -eq "Soup") {
        Write-Host "This chicken eats soup"
} ElseIf ($Animal -eq "Cow") {
    if ($Food -eq "Egg") {
        Write-Host "This cow eats egg"
    } ElseIf ($Food -eq "Soup") {
        Write-Host "This cow eats soup"
} ElseIf ($Animal -eq "Zebra") {
    if ($Food -eq "Egg") {
        Write-Host "This zebra eats egg"
    } ElseIf ($Food -eq "Soup") {
        Write-Host "This zebra eats soup"
```

The script works for the Chicken and the Cow but does not register the zebra portion of the code. I am not sure of what I am doing wrong as there are no errors being returned. Can someone please provide some guidance?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you are trying to achieve here. You would probably have more fun using a [switch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_switch?view=powershell-6). Also, you don't need to check the food, just output the current value of the variable :)

Comment: The code sample you've posted is incomplete (and it most certainly won't work with `$Animal = "Cow"`, because you've nested the `elseif` inside the first `if` statement). Please post code that can actually be executed :)

Comment: You should have the same number of `}`s as `{`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the `}` after your `ElseIf`s.

Corrected code:

```
if ($Animal -eq "Chicken") {
    if ($Food -eq "Egg") {
        Write-Host "This chicken eats egg"
    } ElseIf ($Food -eq "Soup") {
        Write-Host "This chicken eats soup"
    }
} ElseIf ($Animal -eq "Cow") {
    if ($Food -eq "Egg") {
        Write-Host "This cow eats egg"
    } ElseIf ($Food -eq "Soup") {
        Write-Host "This cow eats soup"
    }
} ElseIf ($Animal -eq "Zebra") {
    if ($Food -eq "Egg") {
        Write-Host "This zebra eats egg"
    } ElseIf ($Food -eq "Soup") {
        Write-Host "This zebra eats soup"
    }
}
```

## Better Way

That said, as @MathiasR.Jessen pointed out, this can be simplified using variable expansion:

```
Write-Host "This $($Animal.ToLower()) eats $($Food.ToLower())"
```

See [About Quoting Rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules) for more info.

Comment: Could also be fixed with this one-liner: `Write-Host "This $($Animal.ToLower()) eats $($Food.ToLower())"` :-D

Comment: I am not the batman of question answering (I answer the question you want, not the question you need).

Updated answer with your info ;)

Answer (score 3):

Whilst I fully agree with Doug's answer, I am completely lost as to why you are using if statements in the first place. If this is a learning exercise, I would recommend using a switch statement such as this:

```
$Animal = "Zebra"
$Food = "Soup"
$output = ""

switch ($Animal){
    "Chicken" { $output = "This $($Animal) eat $($Food)"; break}
    "Cow" { $output = "This $($Animal) eat $($Food)"; break }
    "Zebra" { $output = "This $($Animal) eat $($Food)"; break }
}

Write-Output $output
```

or just outputting the values without the unnecessary checking:

```
$Animal = "Zebra"
$Food = "Soup"

Write-Output "This $($Animal) eat $($Food)"
```

Comment: Hi, yes it is a learning exercise. I'm a beginner to PowerShell. Thank you for your feedback and recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

Doug is correct, you missed some `}`

I have re-formatted it for you. I find this formatting helps to catch mistakes like this...

```
if ($Animal -eq "Chicken") 
{
    if ($Food -eq "Egg") 
    {
        Write-Host "This chicken eats egg"
    } 
    ElseIf ($Food -eq "Soup") 
    {
        Write-Host "This chicken eats soup"
    }
}
ElseIf ($Animal -eq "Cow") 
{
    if ($Food -eq "Egg")
    {
        Write-Host "This cow eats egg"
    }
    ElseIf ($Food -eq "Soup")
    {    
        Write-Host "This cow eats soup"
    }
} 
ElseIf ($Animal -eq "Zebra") 
{
    if ($Food -eq "Egg")
    {
        Write-Host "This zebra eats egg"
    } 
    ElseIf ($Food -eq "Soup") 
    {
        Write-Host "This zebra eats soup"
    }
}
```